# Add fullscreen button on nuxt-highcharts with node version 14.8

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, nuxt.js

Hi I'm in existential mode! I want to add a button on highcharts for full screen option, on the documentation it's a lot of useful information but not applicable for nuxt 2.14.7 (highcharts version 8), the new version of nuxt and highcharts have the beautiful "charts context menu"

all the page its on node 14 and nuxt version 2

i will paste the code for someone that could told a starting point for resolve this issue (of course the logical one is to update all dependencies and work with the new stuff)

```
export default {

  
  name: "iotnumberchart",
  props: ["config"],
 
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: ['viewFullscreen', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF']
            }
        }
    },
  data() {
    return {
      receivedTime: 0,
      value: 0,
      time: Date.now(),
      nowTime: Date.now(),
      isMounted: false,
      topic: "",

      chartOptions: {
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        chart: {
          renderTo: "container",
          defaultSeriesType: "line",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
          zoomType: 'xy', // agregue esta linea
          
          
          panning: { enabled: true, type: "xy" },
        events: {
          fullscreenOpen: function () {
                this.update({
                    title: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '30px'
                        }
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        style: {
                            color: 'red'
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            fullscreenClose: function () {
                this.update({
                    title: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        }
                    }
                });
              }
            }
          
        },
        title: {
          text: "",
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: "datetime",
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: "#d4d2d2",
            },
          },
          events: {
      afterSetExtremes: updateLegendLabel
     
    },
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: "",
          },
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: "#d4d2d2",
              font: "11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif",
            },
          },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            label: {
              connectorAllowed: false,
            },
            pointStart: 2010,
          },
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "",
            data: [],
            color: "#e14eca",
          },
        ],
        legend: {
          itemStyle: {
            color: "#d4d2d2",
          },
        },

        responsive: {
          rules: [
            {
              condition: {
                maxWidth: 500,
              },
              chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                  layout: "horizontal",
                  align: "center",
                  verticalAlign: "bottom",
                },

                
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
```

I have tried to use all the examples I have found about this matter from the documentation, also importing manually the models for this functions but I do not have any progress.

I have try also custom functions i found on the web from this links, but also have to make some adapts to try without luck.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ga2fqL0/

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5uv0wsxf/

Comment: Hi, do you mind sharing a snippet with less than 400 lines by narrowing down your issue a bit? Pretty sure nobody wants to spend 3 hours trying to understand your code here.

Comment: HI YES! im sorry, my bad, i have shorten the code for only the configurations of the chart, also at the line 4 starts the declaration of the context button from highcharts, i have tryed that functions and others whitout any succes

Comment: Hi @AgusK, So you want to only show the default context menu? If so, you need to add the `exporting` module. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yd3k5hru/